# Is hour in time range that spans 2 days?

Tags: java, date, time

I've got a function which may only execute within a specific time range. The user can specify this time range by entering a start and end hour.

The problem i bumped into is when the time range spans days. For example:
start range hour: 18 (18:00 6 pm)
end range hour: 6 (06:00 6 am)

A simple:

```
if( hour >= startrange && hour <= endrange ) { now in range }
```

doesn't work in this case.

I'm finding it hard to come up with a solution for this problem. Maybe my mind had enough for today. ( ;) )

Can anybody can point me to a direction?

Comment: You may need to ask for date also, otherwise a message to user saying entered range will be considered as same day.

Comment: I agree with Nambari, if you don't specify days then you COULD just check for overlaps on the 24hr mark. This would cause issues once you have > 1 day though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the startrange > endrange, you have to change the if clause.
So:

```
if (startrange > endrange) {
    if (hour > startrange`) hour = hour -24;
    startrang = startrange -24;
}
if( hour >= startrange && hour <= endrange ) { now in range }
```

Comment: Thank you for your helpful reply. I especially like the simpleness of your solution.

Comment: I think you meant the final check to be *outside* the `if` block.

Comment: It doesn't do any harm, but yeah it should have been ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I'd use [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sf.net) and its `LocalTime` type to represent the times. You can then do:

```
static boolean isInRange(LocalTime start, LocalTime end, LocalTime value) {
    // Avoid equality problems - see description
    if (value.equals(start) || value.equals(end)) {
        return true;
    }
    if (start.compareTo(end) > 0) {
        return !isInRange(end, start, value);
    }
    return start.compareTo(value) < 0 && value.compareTo(end) < 0;
}
```

In other words, you'd generally only end up doing the final comparison with `value` when you'd got a start/end range where `start <= end` - but if you start off with the other way round, then you just invert the result of doing the reverse comparison.

In other words, something is in the range (10pm, 2am) if it's *not* in the range (2am, 10pm).

Alternatively, you could avoid the recursive call:

```
static boolean isInRange(LocalTime start, LocalTime end, LocalTime value) {
    return start.compareTo(end) > 0
        // Reversed: if it's earlier than the end point, or later than the start
        ? value.compareTo(end) <= 0 || start.compareTo(value) <= 0
        : start.compareTo(value) <= 0 && value.compareTo(end) <= 0;
}
```

The tricky bit is equality. The code above assumes that the start/end points are both inclusive, either way round. If you want anything else, you'll need to think very carefully about every situation.

Comment: But, how does this solve time which spans over day? When input is just 2, 6 etc.,

Comment: @Nambari: Read the expanded answer.

Comment: I would also like to thank you for the reply. It is quite extensive that even i understand the idea and logical behind the code.